# Can Someone Help me to Correct my shortcode for displaying a category?

Tags: shortcode, debug

Actually the problem is in this code that is, If I put the id directly in "terms" of any post type like; `[arts-list 10]`, then this type of post which contains this id displays the posts on the frontend but if I put something else like `terms => 'type'` and then I try to display a specific type posts like; `[arts-list type=10]`, no post displays on the frontend, actually in terms I think I have to pass parameter of shortcode but how I do, I can't debug this, that's why I asked you. I hope now you understand what is my problem.

```
function diwp_create_shortcode_arts_post_type(){
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'type' => ' ',
    ), $atts );
 
    $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'arts',
                    'posts_per_page' => '10',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'tax_query'     => array( array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'Types',
                                'field'     => 'term_id',
                                'terms'     =>  '10',
                            ) )
                 );
 
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) :
            $query->the_post() ;      
        $result .= '<div class="art-item">';
        $result .= '<div class="art-image">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
        $result .= '<div class="art-name">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
        $result .= '<div class="art-desc">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
        $result .= '</div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;    
    return $result;            
}
add_shortcode( 'arts-list', 'diwp_create_shortcode_arts_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I have to pass parameter of shortcode, but how I do

Yes, that's correct, and you already are passing the parameter to your shortcode when you do `[arts-list type=10]` — although you should enclose the parameter value in quotes, i.e. `type="10"`.

But the `$atts` in your shortcode *function* is not defined before the [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) is called, so the function should be defined as follows:

```php
function diwp_create_shortcode_arts_post_type( $atts )
```

And because the function is already parsing the parameters which are stored in the `$atts` array, then you just need to use the parameters in your `tax_query` (i.e. taxonomy query) clause:

```php
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Types',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    =>  wp_parse_id_list( $atts['type'] ),
    ),
),
```

Note: In the above example, I used [`wp_parse_id_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/) so that we can pass a list of term IDs, e.g. `[arts-list type="10,11,12"]`. But more importantly, make sure the IDs point to valid terms in the `Types` taxonomy.

Comment: Yes It is So helpful and thanks for your correct guidance when I put your code into my function.php file it worked and I really amazed, so again really really thanks...

Comment: In that case, then I'd appreciate if you can mark my answer as "correct" - just tick the check-mark next to my answer. :)

Comment: As you said, I had tick the check-mark...

Comment: Thanks a lot! (PS: I've just edited the 3rd paragraph that mentions `$atts`..)

Comment: Thanks For your Kindness, I Hope we will talk soon...